# HTML in PHP problem

Tags: php, images, html, customization

I have the following code but I always get an error, it's the first time I've tried to merge HTML with PHP:

```
<?php
if(get_field('post_image'))
{
    echo '<img src="'. get_field('post_image') .'" />';
}
else {
    echo '<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/images/default.jpg" />';
}
?>
```

Is there something wrong the blog info area? Is there an easier way to integrate these?

Thanks

Comment: Mark right answer

Comment: Plain PHP syntax questions are on topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Perhaps, but it's harder to tell what the problem is when it could be related to the code WP provides and the way I've used it, though easier to tell once it's solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error because you try to call php inside php. Try to use this snippet and see what is different:

```
<?php
if(get_field('post_image'))
{
    echo '<img src="'. get_field('post_image') .'" />';
}
else {
    echo '<img src="' . get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/images/images/default.jpg" />';
}
?>
```

Also pay attention that `bloginfo` immediately prints value, when `get_bloginfo` returns it.

Comment: Apart from the second 'images' in the URL, this worked brilliantly. So a single quote and some concatenation solve this in all instances? Thank you

Comment: I've added comments to my answer

Answer (score 0):

bloginfo() echo's its result you need [get_bloginfo()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo)
Also the Else echo is just wrong

the else should be:

```
echo '<img src="'.get_bloginfo('template_url').'/images/images/default.jpg" />';
```

Comment: Still get an error even with that:


Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\sites\kennedy\wp-content\themes\kennedy\side-home.php on line 19

Comment: read my update. You did it right in the first echo